# How can I make seperate navigation for each bottom nav view without recreation fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to make navigation like Instagram navigation. First five fragment should not be created after that called once.

Answer (score 0):

There are three way

1. make custom stack of fragment [link of demo](https://github.com/NikhilVadoliya/InstagramLikeTabView)
2. make five different fragment container and push fragment in it's container.
   for example:

   ```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:orientation="horizontal">

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+id/fragment_container_post"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1" />

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+id/fragment_container_message"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:visibility="gone" />

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+id/fragment_container_add_post"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:visibility="gone" />

           <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+id/fragment_like"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:visibility="gone" />

           <FrameLayout
                   android:id="@+id/fragment_profile"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:visibility="gone" />  

       </LinearLayout>
       <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
           android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"
           app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottombar_item"
           app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_bottombar_item"
           android:background="@color/white"
           app:onNavigationItemSelected="@{viewModel.onNavigationClick}"
           app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu"
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Make viewpager with not swipable and set `OffsetLimit` 5